# How to resolve access denied after saving a bad bucket policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Using terraform I've setup my stack, I just altered the bucket policy and applied but now I've found the bucket policy is denying all actions including management and altering the policy.

How might I update the policy so I can delete the bucket?

I am not able to access the bucket policy any more, but what was applied is still in my terraform state. If I attempt a destroy on the bucket it reveals the following (I've masked id's and account).

The following is just a sample as there are 5 action blocks and each contains a dozen userid's.

```
              - Statement = [
                  - {
                      - Action    = [
                          - "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                          - "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                          - "s3:ListBucket",
                        ]
                      - Condition = {
                          - StringLike    = {
                              - aws:userid = [
                                  - "AROAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXA:*",
                                  - "AROAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXB:*",
                                ]
                            }
                          - StringNotLike = {
                              - aws:userid = [
                                  - "*:AROAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXA:user1",
                                  - "*:AROAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXA:user2",
                                  - "*:AROAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXA:*",
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                      - Effect    = "Deny"
                      - Principal = "*"
                      - Resource  = "arn:aws:s3:::my-account-bucket-name"
                      - Sid       = "Deny bucket-level read operations except for authorised users"
                    },
```

Comment: What is your bucket policy? What was it before when it worked?

Comment: Before, there was no policy. Now it contains conditions for `"StringNotLike": { "aws:userid": ["xxx", "yyy"] }`.

Comment: Can you please actually show full policy? And how do you access the bucket?

Comment: @Marcin I've included a sample. I can't access the policy anymore since I applied it because it's blocking me from accessing it so I've shown the policy from the terraform state which is just a sample.

Comment: I guess that in aws console you can't delete the policy as well? If so you may need to login as root user as explained in [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-accidentally-denied-access/).

Comment: Thanks @Marcin. For now the workaround was to detach the bucket from my state, then create with an alternate name. I don't own the account so have requested assistance from my manager. I'm not stressed about it as it's our nonprod account. It's one of those situations akin to leaving your keys inside, except this time the lock changed when I closed the door. Add your comment as an answer so I can mark as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments.

It seems that the new policy resulted in denying access to everyone. In such cases, AWS explains what to do in a blog post titled:

- [I accidentally denied everyone access to my Amazon S3 bucket. How do I regain access?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-accidentally-denied-access/)

The process involves accessing the account as `root` user and deleting the bucket policy.